# automatic elastic-apm .Net-Agent configuration on k8s

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-apm

I want to automatically feed elastic credentials to my .net-Agent running on the same k8s cluster.

To get passwords I used the following scripts from their [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/master/k8s-request-elasticsearch-endpoint.html):

```
USERNAME="elastic"
PW=$(kubectl get secret "$NAME-es-elastic-user" -o go-template='{{.data.elastic | base64decode }}')
```

In their [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/apm-api.html) they mention that I could use credentials as API-key

```
... where {credentials} is the base64 encoding of id and api_key joined by a colon.

Alternatively, you can create a user and use their username and password to authenticate API access: -u $USER:$PASSWORD.
```

I tried using `elastic:generatedpassword` and the same as base64 encoded string. Both do not work and give an ("syntax" or authentication) error:

```
fail: Elastic.Apm[0]
      {PayloadSenderV2} Failed sending event. Events intake API absolute URL: https://elastic-apm-http:8200/intake/v2/events. APM Server response: status code: Unauthorized, content: 
      {"error":"authentication failed: illegal base64 data at input byte 7"}

fail: Elastic.Apm[0]
      {PayloadSenderV2} Failed sending event. Events intake API absolute URL: https://elastic-apm-http:8200/intake/v2/events. APM Server response: status code: Unauthorized, content: 
      {"error":"authentication failed"}
```

So I thought that I likely missread the docs and authentication with password is not via `Authorization: ApiKey {credentials}` as given in the headline, but basic auth. (however I don't know how to setup this in .net Agent)
The alternative solution would be using the API key. (here I also don't found any resources how to get them within k8s. However I found a http-[API for creating keys](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-api-key.html) - which maybe would be a complicated workaround)

**I'm looking for the correct (and preferable easiest) solution to obtain the configuration for elastic-apm agents on an k8s cluster.**

Comment: Depending on how you configured your agent - you can set configurations for the .NET Agent. Here is the list of all the configs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/config-all-options-summary.html - the 1. is the API Key.

If you pass an IConfiguration to the .NET APM agent when you configured it, you can just set `ApiKey` in your appsettings.json - like here: https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-dotnet/blob/master/sample/SampleAspNetCoreApp/appsettings.json#L9-L15 (No ApiKey there, but just addd it like the other configs).

Comment: If you used the zero code change agent option, then just set the ELASTIC_APM_API_KEY environment variable.

Comment: @gregkalapos Thank you for your comment. In the config list I don't find any option how to set authentication to Basic/credentials. My issue is that I did not find a way to get the API key within k8s. Setting the config via environment Variables like `ELASTICAPM__APIKEY` works for me.